# How to use estimateRigidTransform in OpenCV 3.0 or higher, Is there any other alternative?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video-processing

I want to use estimateRigidTransform function of OpenCV but it throws up an error.

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        30 
>        31   #Find transformation matrix
>   ---> 32   m = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(prev_pts, curr_pts, fullAffine=False) #will only work with OpenCV-3 or less
>        33 
>        34   # Extract traslation
>
> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute
>   'estimateRigidTransform'

my openCV version is 4.0.0.

Answer (score 13):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga762cbe5efd52cf078950196f3c616d48) of `estimateRigidTransform`, this function has been deprecated:

> **Deprecatd:** Use cv::estimateAffine2D, cv::estimateAffinePartial2D instead. If you are using this fuction with images, extract points using cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK and then use the estimation fuctions.

`cv::estimateAffine2D` should be more robust to noise, but more computationally expensive than `cv::estimateAffinePartial2D`. They are similar to `estimateRigidTransform` with the `fullAffine` parameter set to `true` or `false`, respectively.

Comment: new_t = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(img, anchor, fullAffine=False) where size of anchor = (1280, 1920) and size of img = (1280, 1920) doesn't work. I replace estimageRigidTransofrm with estimateAffice2d(img, anchor) and receives this error cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/ptsetreg.cpp:831: error: (-215:Assertion failed) count >= 0 && to.checkVector(2) == count in function 'estimateAffine2D'
 How to make corrections?

Comment: If I am reading your message correctly, you are feeing whole (1280 x 1920) images into both functions? -You are only meant to give them pairs of matching points from both the src and dst image.

Comment: @DiarmaidOCualain Can you please explain What 'pairs of Marching Points from both the src and dst image' mean?

Comment: I mean pairs of matching points: An (x, y) point in the source (src) image, and an (x, y) point in the destination (dst) image make a pair.